# Rails: Display user's liked post & own their posts on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm fairly new to rails & I've been stuck on this problem for some hours. I am trying to display the posts the user has liked and the user's actual posts.

With my current code, I'm getting this error "undefined method `title' for #" and it's being extracted from this line: "<%= link_to post.title, post %>".

Coud anyone shed some light as to how I can get this to work? (more code below)

```
def show
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])

if @user
    @posts = @user.posts.all + @user.likes.all
    render actions: :show
    @likes = @user.likes.all
else
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end
end
```

Here's my routes file:

```
resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :posts

devise_scope :user do
  get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
  get 'edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit'
  get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Here's the 'show' view:

```
<% if @posts %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

"**<%= link_to post.title, post %> display <%= post.inspect %>**" here's the results

```
<Post id: 11, title: "testing123", user_id: 2, created_at: "2013-05-18 19:25:45", updated_at: "2013-05-18 19:25:45"> #<Like id: 23, post_id: 10, user_id: 2, created_at: "2013-05-18 21:39:17", updated_at: "2013-05-18 21:39:17">
```

It works when I just use this -> `@posts = @user.posts.all` but the problem starts when I use this -> `@posts = @user.posts.all + @user.likes.all`

which gives me the **"undefined method `title'"** message..

Comment: Could you post your routes file?

Comment: @derek_duncan just added my routes file above (edited)

Comment: Could you also show view where is that line ? <%= link_to post.title, post %>

Comment: @lis2 just edited it in there above

Comment: Strange, could you instead of <%= link_to post.title, post %> display <%= post.inspect %> to be sure that you really get post objects ?

Comment: @lis2 just edited that in above with some more detail

Comment: last question how looks likes table ? just user_id, post_id ?

Comment: @lis2 yup, just user_id & post_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add something to the user model...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_posts, :through => :likes, :source => :post

  ...

end
```

Then, in your controller you can do this

```
@posts = @user.posts + @user.liked_posts
```

Comment: Wow this worked! still getting used to the associations in rails.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - the 'source' is the often the confusing part.  It's the 'belongs_to' in the join model that you use to perform the :through.  in this case, the post association is how we get through likes without calling it 'posts' explicitly (since that was taken already).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in active record it will be faster than using ruby map

```
@posts = Post.joins("left join likes on likes.post_id = posts.id").
where("posts.user_id ? OR likes.user_id = ?", @user.id, @user.id)
```

Probably better will be to define scope in post model

```
scope :owned_or_liked_by, ->(user) { joins("left join likes on likes.post_id = posts.id").
where("posts.user_id ? OR likes.user_id = ?", user.id, user.id) }
```

And then you can use

```
@posts = Post.owned_or_liked_by(@user)
```

Other solutions will also work, but that generates you one sql query and it will be faster when you will have a lot amount of data.

Comment: Yes, there will about a lot of posts. So I'll try this out because I would like for it to be light and fast

Comment: great, please let me know if it works, but there is still a chance that I didn't make a mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `@user.likes@` doesn't return a `Post` related Array or ActiveRelation.

If assuming that a `Like` object has a `post_id` attribute, then you might want to modify the code as such:

`@posts = @user.posts.all + @user.likes.map(&:post)`

Comment: I figured this was the problem after using the post.inspect method but now I'm getting this error "undefined method `posts' for #<Like..." using your method (still using post.inspect to inspect it)

Comment: What does your `Like` class look like?

Comment: It's likely @user.likes.map(&:post) (not 'posts')

Comment: I see now. This works perfectly.. Wondering if it's still necessary for me to use the "has_many :liked_posts, :through => :likes, :source => :post" in my user model. Works with out it right now but hopefully I won't have any problems in the future when I start implementing more on to it. Thanks, you two

Comment: This will work, but it loads unnecessary ruby objects and does a lot of queries - one query for the likes, then one for each of the posts (1 + n).  Something to keep in mind and avoid when you can.

Comment: @Swards would you prefer your method (user.liked_posts) or lis2's method using 'scope'?

Comment: I posted another approach that I also use sometimes.  In general - I'd try to minimize the number of queries you do while keeping the code readable enough to maintain and understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach you can take, a way to put it into one query and potentially sort.  If you want to include it all in one list.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.visible_to(user)
    where('posts.user_id = :user_id or likes.user_id = :user_id', { :user_id => user.id}).includes(:likes).order('created_at desc')
  end

end
```

Then in the controller, you'd do

```
@posts = Post.visible_to(@user)
```

Comment: This looks a lot cleaner & lighter but not it's throwing me this error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Comment: I removed the "sort('created_at desc')" and now it's working. Thank you. One quick question though - would it be feasible to have the likes sorted as they are liked instead of when they were created? (Exampled, post was created 5 days ago, I liked & now it shows up on my page today ahead of my posts that were created earlier today)

Comment: Sorry that should have been 'order'.  'sort' is an array method, and order is for active record.  Sorting by the child is a little tricky there are potential uniqueness issues, but you could try order('likes.created_at'). You may also try ordering with the has_many through approach.  Make an additional association.  has_many :sorted_likes :class_name => 'Like', :order => 'likes.created_at'.  And then do has_many :sorted_liked_posts :through => :sorted_likes, :source => :post.

Comment: order('likes.created_at') didn't work but I'm going tot try the second one as well as experimenting & reply back showing the solution (if I solve it). Thank you again @Swards

Comment: tried the second approach with no avail.. Stick can't get it sorted out :(.. The posts sort out fine but when I like a post, it shows up on the user's page when it was created (behind all of his posts that were already posted), instead of when it was 'liked' (ahead of his posts that were already posted). I'm going to still to get this worked out but if anyone could lend a hand, that would be much help

Comment: Take a look at the sql that's generated (either in the logs or with a .to_sql).  Try it in your sql ui to see what it generates.  You may get some clues there to why it's not working.